# How to scrape a table on a web page into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I want to scrape a table on a page into a dataframe with columns name of "Contracts" and "Funding Rate".(https://www.binance.com/en/futures/funding-history/1)

This is what i have tried so far but still can't work out. Appreciate if anyone can help me out of this.

```
from pandas.io.html import read_html
import lxml.html as lh

url="https://www.binance.com/cn/futures/funding-history/1"

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

text = soup.get_text()

text1= soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "bnc-table-row-cell-break-word"})

text1.find_all("tr")
```

The image attached is the dataframe what i want to generate through pandas.

[image]

Comment: The data on that page isn't part of the base HTML page, so you can't parse it using BeautifulSoup. The data is provided by a dynamic call to https://www.binance.com/gateway-api/v1/public/future/common/get-funding-rate-history.

Comment: So I have to use api in order to generate a dataframe?

Comment: You can either use the API or use a browser-mimicking technology like Splash or Selenium.

Comment: API (https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#change-log) seems not to provide   real time data. I will have a look of selenium. THX